# How to configure v3 Bot using Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework

We are running chatbots using BotFramework v3. Now Microsoft changed from 'Bot Channel Registration' to 'Azure Bot' service which uses a key vault. Until that the bot had to be configured by storing the Microsoft app id and app password in Web.config or the app services app settings. Now we only get the app id but no password because it's managed by identities and stored in the key vault.

Incoming messages arrive at the bot but outgoing messages raises 'Unauthorized' error.

How can we configure the BF v3 bot correctly? We used UserAssignedMSI as bot type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AP01, this was very useful.

Creating a Azure Bot resource of type MultiTenant solved my problem. Under "Configuration" you can manage the app password and generate a new secret. Be sure to set its lifetime to 24 month and make a note to your future self to renew it after 2 years. Set the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` in the web-apps app settings and `MicrosoftAppType` to `MultiTenant`.

There is no need for creating a key vault and an identity resource (I got these 2 when I've created the Azure Bot resource of type `UserAssignedMSI`).

Answer (score 0):

Bot Framework v3 is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-availability?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-framework-sdk-version-3-lifetime-support-and-deprecation-notice) alongside the Bot Channels Registration. Support for v3 ended in 2019, and as such it is no longer recommended to use v3.

While [existing workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned#create-the-resource) will continue to work, you should not modify the Azure resources unnecessarily. Support for the `UserAssignedMSI` application type in Azure Bots is new. If you want to use the newer Azure Bot resource and app types, you will need to upgrade your bots to SDK v4. Refer to the [migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) for details on migrating bots from v3 to v4.

Comment: We know that it is deprecated and are working on the migration. But the bot is complex and there ist simply not enough manpower to migrate the bot and handle the daily business. We were forced to delete the whole resource group because of an exception that was thrown while publishing. The app service wasn't able to resolve the name of the storage account, which sounded like an internal DNS problem of Azure. If there is really no way to get the bot running again then we're screwed...

Comment: Try the `MultiTenant` option instead of `UserAssignedMSI`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. We already tried SingleTenant and it did not work, although with this type we get a password that can be put into the Web.conf.

Comment: You were right. Using MultiTenant works. Thanks alot.

Comment: You're welcome. Single Tenant is also newer and came about after the launch of v4. v3 bots only ever used MultiTenant.